# i want to write a php code to fill text box by clicking a hyperlink

Tags: php

i am student learning php.
I have write a code to insert name,address,dob to insert in database. for that i have taken 2 textbox for name and dob, and a textarea for address. I have created 4 columns in info(name of table) id,name,address,dob. among which id is the key and is autofilled. And i am done with the inserting and dispalying inserted data on page in table like structure. while displaying the records on web page i displayed them in table form along with two links edit and delete at each row.
now the task is that when i click on edit button the text boxes which is previously used to take input from user are get filled with respective record where that clicked edit link resides.
And if "delete" link get clicked then respective record should be deleted.
The problem is that i am not understanding how to write a code to edit and delete record by clicking that links.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

set the link of the edit to something like this: `?function=edit&id=".$postid."` and link it to the side itself.

```
if($_GET['function']=='edit'){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM <your-tabel> WHERE ID = ".$_GET['id']." ";
  // query that sql
  $name = $row['name'];
  // do the same for your other fields
```

Then use the data in the text-area:

```
<textarea  name="name"><?=$name;?><testarea>
```

This should get you your data back into the textarea and therefor the user can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

For editing,

```
give an hyperlink as follows,

<a href="edit.php?id=1">Edit</a>
```

edit.php

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$query = "UPDATE {table_name} SET {colume_name=value} WHERE id='$id'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
header('Location:your_page.php');
```

For deleting,

```
give an hyperlink as follows,

<a href="delete.php?id=1">Delete</a>
```

delete.php

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE id='$id'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
header('Location:your_page.php');
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: could you tell me how to use that $id in mysql query to select particular record.

Comment: @SanketRajurkar :- $id should contain the id value from the mysql